# Displaying the running balance but only the specified rows using WHERE clause in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have two table named nca and issue_details describes below with values:

```
Table: nca
+--------+--------+------------+-------------+--------------+
| nca_id | nca_no | issue_date | nca_amount  | account_type |
+--------+--------+------------+-------------+--------------+
|      1 | 001    | 2015-01-11 | 19264373.46 | ROP          |
|      2 | 002    | 2015-01-11 |     1752000 | ROP          |
|      3 | 001    | 2015-01-11 |      200000 | DBP-TRUST    |
|      4 | 002    | 2015-01-11 |     3000000 | DBP-TRUST    |
+--------+--------+------------+-------------+--------------+

Table: issue_details
+----------+------------+----------+----------+-------+
| check_no | issue_date | issue_amount | account_type | 
+----------+------------+--------------+----------+---+
|        1 | 2015-01-11 |         2800 | ROP          | 
|        2 | 2015-01-11 |         2800 | ROP          |    
|        3 | 2015-01-11 |      1999.17 | ROP          |    
|        5 | 2015-01-11 |       200000 | DBP-TRUST    |  
|        6 | 2015-01-11 |       200000 | DBP-TRUST    |  
+----------+------------+--------------+----------+---+
```

I want to display its running balance subtracted to each issue_amount from issue_details table to
the sum of nca_amount from nca table having the same issue_date and account_type. In my two tables,
heres what I want to happen:

First, **Sum up** all the nca_amount where issue_date = 2015-01-11 and account_type = ROP.

Second, **Subtract** the result from the first step to each issue_amount from the issue_details table where issue_date = 2015-01-11 and account_type = ROP. Shown below :

Sum of of this two rows is **2,101,6373.46**

```
+--------+--------+------------+-------------+--------------+
| nca_id | nca_no | issue_date | nca_amount  | account_type |
+--------+--------+------------+-------------+--------------+
|      1 | 001    | 2015-01-11 | 19264373.46 | ROP          |
|      2 | 002    | 2015-01-11 |     1752000 | ROP          |
```

Then subtract to each issue_amount from issue_details table where issue_date = 2015-01-11 and account_type = ROP would be :

21,016,373.46 - 2,800 = **21,013,573.46**, 
21,013,573.46 - 2,800 = **21,010,773.46**, 
21,010,773.46 - 1,999.17 = **21,008,774.29**

Fortunately, someone gave me this code to display the running balance and I added a where clause to display only the data where account_type = 'ROP' and issue_date = '2015-01-10' :

```
SELECT r.*,
 (@tot := @tot - issue_amount) as bank_balance
 FROM (SELECT @tot := SUM(nca_amount) as nca_total FROM nca
    WHERE account_type = 'ROP' AND 
    issue_date = '2015-01-11'
  )
vars CROSS JOIN issue_details r
ORDER BY r.issue_date, r.check_no;
```

and heres what happen :

```
+----------+------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+
| check_no | issue_date | issue_amount | account_type | bank_balance |
+----------+------------+--------------+--------------+---------------
|        1 | 2015-01-11 |         2800 | ROP          |  21013573.46 | 
|        2 | 2015-01-11 |         2800 | ROP          |  21010773.46 |
|        3 | 2015-01-11 |      1999.17 | ROP          |  21008774.29 |
|        5 | 2015-01-11 |       200000 | DBP-TRUST    |  20808774.29 |  -- wrong
|        6 | 2015-01-11 |       200000 | DBP-TRUST    |  20608774.29 |  -- wrong
+----------+------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+
```

heres what I want to display :

```
+----------+------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+
| check_no | issue_date | issue_amount | account_type | bank_balance |
+----------+------------+--------------+--------------+---------------
|        1 | 2015-01-11 |         2800 | ROP          |  21013573.46 | 
|        2 | 2015-01-11 |         2800 | ROP          |  21010773.46 |
|        3 | 2015-01-11 |      1999.17 | ROP          |  21008774.29 |
+----------+------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+
```

Only the rows having the field of issue_date = '2015-01-11' and account_type = 'ROP'.
Can anyone help me re- code that query above to display that result ? Thanks.

Comment: Don't you want something like `WHERE issue_data <= '2015-01-11'` (less-than-or-equal instead of equal)? Since you want the full history up to a date.

Comment: What I want to display is those fields having the account_type='ROP' and issue_date='2015-01-11'. No rows should be displayed having the account_type of 'DBP-TRUST' and having an another problem is the calculated bank_balance of DBP-TRUST is wrong , only the ROP is correct. What is wrong with my query above?

Comment: If it was me, just for the example, I'd pretend that the numbers were something simpler e.g. 300, 400, 500

Comment: `CROSS JOIN`?  Really?  Is your starting data set every possible combination of the rows of your two tables?  That seems unlikely to me (but I don't understand your data). It seems likely to me that each row in your `issue_details` table is related to exactly one row in your `nca` table. But it isn't clear what that relation should be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use can use having or where in your query. Please check this query 
(1)  Where :

```
SELECT r.*,
 (@tot := @tot - issue_amount) as bank_balance
 FROM (SELECT @tot := SUM(nca_amount) as nca_total FROM nca
    WHERE account_type = 'ROP' AND 
    issue_date = '2015-01-11'
  )
vars CROSS JOIN issue_details r
WHERE r.account_type != 'DBP-TRUST'
ORDER BY r.issue_date, r.check_no
```

(2) Having :

```
SELECT r.*,
 (@tot := @tot - issue_amount) as bank_balance
 FROM (SELECT @tot := SUM(nca_amount) as nca_total FROM nca
    WHERE account_type = 'ROP' AND 
    issue_date = '2015-01-11'
  )
vars CROSS JOIN issue_details r
HAVING r.account_type != 'DBP-TRUST'
ORDER BY r.issue_date, r.check_no
```